# CustomControl DependencyProperty not binding when used in DataGrid's DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I made a `CustomControl` which is an `IPBox` with a `DependencyProperty` named IPAddress :

```
public partial class IPBox : UserControl
{
    public IPBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty IPAddressProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IPAddress", typeof(string), typeof(IPBox), new PropertyMetadata("127.0.0.1"));
    [Bindable(true)]
    public string IPAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(IPAddressProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            string[] splitValues = value.Split('.');
            txtboxFirstPart.Text = splitValues[0];
            txtboxSecondPart.Text = splitValues[1];
            txtboxThridPart.Text = splitValues[2];
            txtboxFourthPart.Text = splitValues[3];
            SetValue(IPAddressProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I want to use it in a `DataGrid` within a `DataGridTemplateColumn` :

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}" 
    Background="Black"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IP Address" Width="150">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Controls:IPBox 
                        IPAddress="{Binding OSCMessenger.Address, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Port" Width="150">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="{Binding OSCMessenger.Port}"
                        />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The `TextBlock` binding to `OSCMessenger.Port` is working as expected, but for some reason my `CustomControl` which is binding to  `OSCMessenger.Address` is not.
I tested this `CustomControl` in a `UserControl` and it is working fine, only when used in a `GridCell` then it is not while not Binding error message are thrown.

Why ?

EDIT--

This is the XAML for the IPBOX :

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMiX.MVVM.Controls.IPBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox
        Name="txtboxFirstPart" 
        LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
        TextChanged="txtbox_TextChanged" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="0"  
        MaxLength="3" 
        TabIndex="1" 
        PreviewKeyDown="txtboxFirstPart_PreviewKeyDown" 
        />
    <Label 
        Content="." 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.Row="0"   
        />
    <TextBox 
        Name="txtboxSecondPart" 
        LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
        Grid.Column="2" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        MaxLength="3" 
        TextChanged="txtbox_TextChanged" 
        TabIndex="2" 
        KeyDown="txtboxSecondPart_KeyDown" 
        />
    <Label 
        Content="." 
        Grid.Column="3" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        />
    <TextBox  
        Name="txtboxThridPart" 
        LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
        Grid.Column="4" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        MaxLength="3" 
        TextChanged="txtbox_TextChanged" 
        TabIndex="3" 
        KeyDown="txtboxThridPart_KeyDown" 
        />
    <Label 
        Content="." 
        Grid.Column="5" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        />
    <TextBox 
        x:Name="txtboxFourthPart" 
        Grid.Column="6" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        MaxLength="3" 
        TextChanged="txtbox_TextChanged" 
        LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
        TabIndex="4" 
        />
</Grid>
```

Comment: ok I will remove that then.

Comment: both direction doesn't work actually

Comment: there is no binding error, I use the IPBox somewhere else and bind it to the same property but the IPBox within DataGrid doesn't update. Also if I try to change the value it get back to the default one : "127.0.0.1"

Comment: I just added more infos, the IPBox split the IP address and display it in different textbox basically.

Comment: You must not call anything else than SetValue in the setter of a dependency property, because (as already said) the setter is simply not called when the property is set in XAML or by a Binding or by some other sources. You have to register a PropertyChangedCallback.

Comment: ok I will try that. Thank you.